# Проблемы с авторизацией ВК, при запуске приложения

Tags: android, vkontakte-api

Первый раз при запуске приложения должен выводится запрос на доступ к аккаунту ВК. При полученном разрешении, повторный запуск приложения не должен выводить запрос на доступ и сразу переходить на onActivityResult. Но окно на доступ не выводится, т.к. не проходит авторизация и следовательно далее никаких движений нет. Где что упустил, не могу понять.

```
MainActivity.class
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String[] scope = new String[]{VKScope.OFFLINE};

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

 //если пользователь не зарегистрирован,то выводится окно на доступ
    if(!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) 
       VKSdk.login(this,scope);
    }



Application.class
public class Application extends android.app.Application{
VKAccessTokenTracker vkAccessTokenTracker = new VKAccessTokenTracker() {
    @Override
    public void onVKAccessTokenChanged(VKAccessToken oldToken, VKAccessToken newToken) {
        if (newToken == null) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Application.this, MainActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }
};
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    vkAccessTokenTracker.startTracking();
    VKSdk.initialize(this);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Вы неверно строите логику приложения.

В первый раз, проверив, что юзер не залогинен, т.е. токена нет, надо авторизовать юзера.

После этого, проверив, что токен есть, надо запустить далее вашу активити как-то так:

```
//если пользователь не зарегистрирован,то выводится окно на доступ
if(!VKSdk.isLoggedIn()) 
    VKSdk.login(this,scope);
} else {
    //запускаем нужную активити:
    Intent intent = new Intent(Application.this, MainActivity.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK|Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Comment: У меня далее идёт не запуск другой активити. После удачного логина идёт выполнение :
    `@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, 
    Intent data) { ... }`
@ЮрийСПб, подскажите, как в таком случае выполнить ветку `else` ?

Comment: Добавил так, но не идёт всё равно.
`...
 else  onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

@Override protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) { ... }`

Comment: @ШураБалаганов, onActivityResult должен вызываться только один раз - при логине. Более он вызываться не должен. Вам надо код оттуда выполнить в `else` вот и всё. Т.е. копирнуть или вынести в отдельный метод.